# SQL decimal truncation not rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is the sql i wrote but looking for 5 digits after decimal without rounding.

```
Select convert(decimal(10,5),Cast(473 as float) / Cast(14322 as float))  --i get 0.03303
Select Cast(473 as float) / Cast(14322 as float) --i get 0.033026113671275
```

But i'm looking for 0.03302.
Five digits after decimal which (03302) with out rounding.
The first query is rounding it off to `0.3303` instead of `0.03302`

Let me know.

Comment: Doesn't affect the answer, but any particular reason you're casting as `FLOAT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ROUND`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) with the optional third parameter to truncate:

```
Select convert(decimal(10,5),
    ROUND(Cast(473 as float) / Cast(14322 as float)
    ,5,1   // the 1 tells SQL to truncate instead of round
    ))
```

Comment: I was going to say, I don't think it's that big a secret. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yeah I figured that since it's _documented_ then it's not really a secret - just not well known (at least not to me) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,5), 473 / (14322 * 1.0) - 0.000005);
```